# FastReport barcode align to center

Tags: report, fastreport

I load barcode from database where is different size (eg. 4 character or 13 character) Is it possible align barcode to center of page regardless of size.

This is my example where is different size (1 and 3 is OK).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the Align property of the `TfrxBarCodeView` object to `baCenter`?